# how to write into a windows command window from python

Tags: python, windows, window, command, python-2.6

I am using Python 2.6
I'd like to enter instructions into a command windows from python.
I just need the right method. However as an indication, I am showing several failed trials.
Here are several trials and the error types I get:

first trial

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = subprocess.communicate('cd Documents')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'communicate'
```

Second trial:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("cd Documents")
```

No error message, however nothing happens. Il i try to open a folder that doesn't exist , I get the same thing. The command window stays empty

Third trial:

```
os.system('cd Documents')
```

Nothing happens , it returns 1, however if i try to open a folder that doesn't exist, it returns 1 too:

```
os.system('cd Documentss')
```

Last trial

```
a=os.popen("C:\\system32\\cmd.exe",'w')
a.write("cd Documents")
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: why do you need to do this? Isn't `os.chdir("C:\\..")` enough?

Answer (score 3):

Your first trial is correct, except for the fact that you're calling the module instead of your newly instantiated class. You need to use

`proc.communicate('cd Documents')`

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. If I'm doing this I dn't get the error message anymore. However, if I'm writing this, the window is jsut closing whethere the file exists or not. Also nothing appears on the command window after the first line was written

Answer (score 1):

Your third trial:

```
 os.system('your command')
```

works. I used and it's ok:

```
os.system('ipconfig -renew') # Renew all connections windows
```

Try:

```
os.system('ipconfig -release') # you will disconnect from your network
```

Then use:

```
os.system('ipconfig -renew') # network will back
```