# Interact with the Windows CMD in python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to open a windows CMD and read/write into it. 
I managed to open the CMD with this command:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe')
```

To write into the CMD console, I tried the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702909/how-to-write-into-a-windows-command-window-from-python):

```
proc.communicate('cd Documents')
```

This line automatically closed the CMD, so i wasn't able to see if it worked.

How can I read and write into the Windows CMD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`communicate` sends the contents of the buffer to standard input then closes the input pipe, which ends up terminating the process. So you cannot do something interactive with that.

Moreover, you have to pass `stdin` argument to `Popen` or by default nothing is redirected.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

now you can write lines to `proc.stdin` (don't forget line terminators & binary prefix for python 3 compat.) and see what happens

```
proc.stdin.write(b"cd Documents\n")
```

(okay, you could have used `cwd="Documents"` for that one, but that's for the sake of the example)

In the example, output is *not* redirected. Which means that you'll see the output in the current console. Don't forget to `close` standard input or that won't work (probably because buffer isn't flushed and/or pipe is broken when python quits). Then wait for process to finish with `wait()`

Complete example:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
# do some stuff in between...
proc.stdin.write(b"cd\n")
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

on my computer it prints (excuse my french)

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

L:\so>cd ..

L:\>cd
L:\
```

if you want the process not to terminate, you could use some more tricks:
import subprocess,time

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe',stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(b"cd ..\n")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
time.sleep(1)
input("press return")
proc.stdin.write(b"cd\n")
proc.stdin.flush()
proc.stdin.close()
proc.wait()
```

this sends commands, flushes standard input (but doesn't close it) then waits for the messages to print, and asks for a key to be pressed. You can send more commands after that, as long as you flush each time, and close in the end.

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't work for my. The console still closed after the line:               proc.stdin.write(b"cd Documents\n")

Comment: try the complete example

Comment: I tried your complete example but it still closed the CMD: https://gyazo.com/f197465aedcb2de117af3fca1f258c35 (GIF)

Comment: of course it closes the CMD. But after performing the job. let me edit.

Comment: Ah okey I see. I understood the proc.wait() as the line which leads the to CMD to stay open. Similair like in C# console.ReadKey() .

Comment: How could I know read and save the input into a variable for example?

Comment: you can use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` but the issue is that you have to consume the output or this will block. But consuming the output can also block because the process is not writing anymore.... not as easy, or you have to create 2 threads.

Comment: CMD uses line-buffered text mode, which requires CRLF (i.e. `"\r\n"`) line endings to properly detect a newline and flush a file stream. Also, pass `bufsize=0` to prevent the `proc.stdin` file object in Python from buffering on its side. Then you can interact with CMD without requiring `stdin.flush()` and `stdin.close()` to force each side to flush its buffer. Of course, if you run other executables from this CMD session, they'll inherit the stdin pipe and, because it's a pipe, will likely use *full* buffering, which prevents any reasonable interaction.

Comment: @eryksun that makes sense. I must admit I wasn't too proud of the `stdin.flush()`.